# Is second derivative really accurate?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

It is proven that when $$d^2y/(dx)^2 > 0$$ then the static point in consideration is a minimum point and when $$d^2y/(dx)^2 < 0$$ then the point is a maximum point.

Consider a point of inflection where the gradient at points before it is higher than the gradient at points after it whose gradients are not negative.

Take for example a car travelling with increasing velocity then the car at some point the car stops for a while then the car start again but with speeds lower than before the stop.

That means that $$d^2y/(dx)^2$$ is negative because velocity is lower than before hence the point of stoppage is a maximum point,**but that is not the case** as we can deduce that that was just a point of inflection and not the maximum distance covered.
Hence my question is there any point at which second derivative does not accurately determine concavity.

Comment: Two comments. First: we say **stationary** point, not static point. Apart from that, you are essentially confusing two concepts: that of **local** maximum (or minimum), and that of **global** maximum (or minimum). Derivatives can only give you local information, as you say here.

Comment: So you mean that the point of inflection is essentially a local maximum and if so, then how do we determine global maximum

Comment: This is very confused. If you have a twice-differentiable function, then saying the second derivative vanishes is not good enough to say you have an inflection point. For example, the function $y=x^4$ has second derivative zero at $x=0$, and this is in fact a minimum point. Moreover, if the car stops, having had increasing velocity, then the velocity had to be negative before the stop. If the velocity continues to decrease (you were sloppy and switched to "speed"), it cannot be "lower than before the stop."

Answer (score 1):

If the car "stops for a while" then the second derivative is $0$ for the period when it is stationary, not negative. Additionally the only way that "start[ing] again with a speed lower than before the stop" makes sense is if the car's speed is discontinuous when it stops (i.e. it jumps instantaneously from some positive amount to $0$), but in this case the second derivative doesn't even exist.

Comment: I think the second derivative exists and is acceleration.My question is not on linear equation whose second derivatives do not exist but my question is based on a distance-time curve with the car having some acceleration.